# For some reason my pygame window isn't opening

Tags: python, pygame, window

Working on a pygame RPG game. As of now, I am trying to make a menu system where you can transition from image to image based on your dialogue. However, I am unable to get my window open for a reason I just cannot figure out! Sorry if the spacing seems weird I'm not sure how to format it here correctly, on my pycharm the spacing is for sure all correct. Here is the code from the first file (`game.py`):

```
import pygame

class Game():
 def __init__(self):
    pygame.init()
    self.running, self.playing = True, False
    self.UP_KEY, self.DOWN_KEY, self.START_KEY, self.BACK_KEY = False, False, False, False
    self.DISPLAY_W, self.DISPLAY_H = 800, 700
    self.display = pygame.Surface((self.DISPLAY_W,self.DISPLAY_H))
    self.window = pygame.display.set_mode(((self.DISPLAY_W,self.DISPLAY_H)))
    self.font_name = pygame.font.get_default_font()
    self.BLACK, self.WHITE = (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255)

def game_loop(self):
    while self.playing:
        self.check_events()
        if self.START_KEY:
            self.playing= False
        self.display.fill(self.BLACK)
        self.draw_text('Thanks for Playing', 20, self.DISPLAY_W/2, self.DISPLAY_H/2)
        self.window.blit(self.display, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        self.reset_keys()

def check_events(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.running, self.playing = False, False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                self.START_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                self.BACK_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.DOWN_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.UP_KEY = True

def reset_keys(self):
    self.UP_KEY, self.DOWN_KEY, self.START_KEY, self.BACK_KEY = False, False, False, False

def draw_text(self, text, size, x, y ):
    font = pygame.font.Font(self.font_name,size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, self.WHITE)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = (x,y)
    self.display.blit(text_surface,text_rect)
```

Here is my code in the second file (main.py) next to the game one:

```
from game import Game

g = Game()

while g.running:
   g.playing = True
   g.game_loop()
```

Comment: Try removing the window initialization from the game loop. See what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your indentation in `game.py` is incorrect and because of that your `Game` class instance has no `game_loop()` method — indentation is *very* important in Python. All methods of a class should be indented 1 level further in than the initial `class` statement.

Below is how to do it properly. I strongly suggest that you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```
import pygame

class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.running, self.playing = True, False
        self.UP_KEY, self.DOWN_KEY, self.START_KEY, self.BACK_KEY = False, False, False, False
        self.DISPLAY_W, self.DISPLAY_H = 800, 700
        self.display = pygame.Surface((self.DISPLAY_W,self.DISPLAY_H))
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode(((self.DISPLAY_W,self.DISPLAY_H)))
        self.font_name = pygame.font.get_default_font()
        self.BLACK, self.WHITE = (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255)

    def game_loop(self):
        while self.playing:
            self.check_events()
            if self.START_KEY:
                self.playing= False
            self.display.fill(self.BLACK)
            self.draw_text('Thanks for Playing', 20, self.DISPLAY_W/2, self.DISPLAY_H/2)
            self.window.blit(self.display, (0,0))
            pygame.display.update()
            self.reset_keys()

    def check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running, self.playing = False, False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    self.START_KEY = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.BACK_KEY = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.DOWN_KEY = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.UP_KEY = True

    def reset_keys(self):
        self.UP_KEY, self.DOWN_KEY, self.START_KEY, self.BACK_KEY = False, False, False, False

    def draw_text(self, text, size, x, y ):
        font = pygame.font.Font(self.font_name,size)
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, self.WHITE)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = (x,y)
        self.display.blit(text_surface,text_rect)
```